# Trigger 2 cameras at the same time connected each one in a different USB port of a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

Tags: raspbian, usb

I have two cameras - Canon EOS 700D - connected to different USB ports of a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

How can trigger both cameras at the same time with the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Hello Bex, I'm trying to shoot the 2 cameras simultaneously but only
1 camera can trigger because the raspberry only allows me to use 1 USB port instead of the 2 USB ports.

Comment: What is stopping you from triggering one then triggering the other?

Comment: Hello Joan, I applied the program photo2 in the terminal of the Raspberry. I want to select the 2 USB ports that were detected with the code "gphoto2 --auto-detect". Once detected both ports, I wrote the code " gphoto2 --port=usb:001,006 & gphoto2 --port=usb:001,007 in the terminal to select the 2 USB ports but the program seems that it selects 1 USB port.

Comment: It is better to add new information to your question (with the edit button).